# Better way to find xml node?

Tags: c#, xml

Can anyone tell me if there is a better way to search an XML file and replace a value?
The node could exist anywhere, so can't use xpath.

I can achieve what I want with the following, but just wondering if there is an easier way.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load("c:\\test.xml");

 XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("NameToChange");

 for (int i=0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
 {   
     elemList[i].InnerText = "replacedText";
 }
```

TIA

Dave

Comment: Why can't you use XPath? The ancestor/descendant directions should allow you to find the tag virtually anywhere.

Comment: Looks easy enough to me. You can look at `XDocument` and LINQ to XML though. Not sure you will find anything more succinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think there's no problem with unspecified location when it comes to XPath. Just use the descendant direction 
http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathdescendant.php

The XPath would be:

```
//NameToChange
```

But your solution seems OK if you ask me. The way you did it seems easy.

The main difference that could result from using one solution or the other would be in the difficulty of implementing any changes in the way you want to select your nodes. I'm not familiar with C# libraries but XPath lets you do almost anything in a single line, when it comes to selection of elements.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise I could use XPath to select any occurance. I ended up using: var xmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//NameToChange"); 
   xmlNode.InnerText = "ChangedValue";

Comment: I think it's good to know XPath well. Not only can it be used by many libraries in various programming languages but it is also a basis for many other XML technologies, such as XSLT or XQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendantnodes.aspx) and the XElement etc classes. Personally, I prefer it to XPath because it's integrated directly into the language, instead of relying on strings.

Comment: Yeah, LINQ is a gem. I wish Java had something like this.